# Sending mail to checked mail id's via dynamically generated checkbox CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, email, checkbox

Here i have to write code to send mail to checked mail id's through checkbox with its value given as mail id's but problem arises while i pass the array of checkbox's value to controller via post method its not passing coz when i print the array it gives me an empty array, Please help me over this.

**View.php**

```
 <?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>
                        <?php $attributes = array("name" => "Sendquotation","autocomplete"=>"off");
                        echo form_open("Sendquotation/index", $attributes);?>
<div style="max-height: calc(50vh - 110px);overflow-y: scroll;" class="panel-body col-sm-12 form-group">
            <h3 align="center">Select vendor you want to mail.<br><button class="btn btn-success text-right">Send all</button></h3>


             <?php 
                         foreach($vendorlist as $row)
                            {
                         echo '<input type="checkbox" name="vendor_name[]" value="'.$row->VendorEmail.'"> <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row->VendorName.'</b><hr/><br/>';
                            }
                      ?>
            </div> 
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-file-text"> </i> Send Enquery</button>
                  </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Controller.php**

```
<?php
class Sendquotation extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation'));
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('Gst_model');
    $this->load->model('User_model');

  }

   function index()
  { 
    $vendor_mail= $this->input->post('vendor_name');        
     foreach ($vendor_mail as $mail_id)
      {
        $data = array(
                'vendormailid' => $this->input->post('mail_id')                 
           );

$config = array(
            'protocol' => 'sendmail',
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'UTF-8',
        );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $message =
         '<h3>HTML MAIL</h3>';
        $mail_to = "vendor@yourvendor.com";
        $from_mail = 'kdk020313@gmail.com';
        $from_name = 'EMERSON PVT LTD';
        $reply_to = 'kdk020313@gmail.com';
        $subject = "Online GSTIN Updation!";

        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->from($from_mail, $from_name);
        $this->email->to($data);
        $this->email->cc('innovations@miisky.com');
        $this->email->bcc('kdk020313@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        //$this->email->attach($file);
        if ($this->email->send()) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Mail Succesfully Sent!</div>');
                //redirect('Purchase_master');
            print_r($data);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: first print_r($this->input->post()) to see what you are getting in the post array

Comment: okay i'll do that..!

Comment: yaa..i see now its giving out proper array values that means there is problem in foreach..!!What can it be sir?

Comment: you mind sharing the screenshot of the array or just Edit the post and paste that array .

Comment: sure sill i'll..!!

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFAU3.png

Comment: you could use a < pre> tag to format it a bit better before print_r .

Comment: Here you go sit this is array when i check two checkbox and here i want to access only VendorMail..!

Comment: how many checkboxes do you check before posting the form, it seems nothing was checked before posting the form

Comment: Yes sir other fields contain empty array as they are not mandatory but i want only ==>Array ( [radio] => on [pucrhasetype] => 0 [itemName] => Select Item name [Destination] => [orign] => [billing] => [uom] => [Quantity] => [vendor_name] => Array ( [0] => g.jagan@aarmsvaluechain.com [1] => bn.hariprasad.26@gmail.com ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach ($vendor_mail as $mail_id)
{
  $data = array(
  'vendormailid' =>$mail_id                 
   );
}
```

You see in your post you have an array index vendor_name which has 2 indexes. You have assigned that array to $vendor_mail variable which means $vendor_email has now those 2 indexes , you are iterating that array with a foreach() so why get that index from post array again. foreach ($vendor_mail as $mail_id) means every index of $vendor_mail is now $mail_id.. use it.

Comment: soo sir...Mail To will be $data.!!??

Comment: mail to will be the index of data

Comment: Thanks a ton sir for your assistance.!